# Laravel Middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to do something like this ,Following are the code sample :

```
public function handle()
{
    $user = Auth::user()->name;
    $ABC = ABC::find($id);
    $author = $ABC->author;
    if(!$user == $author){
        echo "He can comment";
    }
    else{
         //delete comment 
    }

    return redirect()->back();

}
```

only owner of the post can add comment I want to do it using middleware, can somebody help me?

Comment: What is your problem exactly. Kindly elaborate more.

Comment: Please *explain* your problem in *brief* with more *description*.

Comment: You can use Policy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example,

```
<?php
  namespace Lame\Http\Middleware\Comment;

  class CanAddComment
  {

      public function handle($request, Closure $next)
      {
          $user = Auth::user()->name;
          $ABC = ABC::find($id);
          $author = $ABC->author;
          if($user == $author){
              return redirect()->back();
          }

          return $next($request);
      }
}
```